# How to install [filename].txz files

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install the video editor cinelerra but the install file is (.txz). I've been looking and I can only find things that explain how to install .tgz or .tar.xz files and such. Could anyone help me with this?

Edit: I now have it installed, when I try to run it, it doesn't do anything. I'm going to try rebooting then I'll add another edit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: @psusi This is not a duplicate of [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) because that question is about installing software from source code. (This one is not.)

Comment: @EliahKagan, how do you figure that?  The only difference is this is about using xz compression instead of gzip or bzip2.

Comment: @psusi I might be misunderstanding you. Are you asking me why I think this isn't about installing from source, or are you saying you know it's not but that you think this overlaps sufficiently with [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file) anyway? This question is specifically about files named `.txz`, an extension that remains somewhat uncommon (even compared to `.tar.xz`) and is specifically what the OP was confused about. And I know the archive contains binaries rather than sources because I checked (and wrote about that in my answer).

Comment: @EliahKagan, I suppose, but I don't think that difference is enough to merit a separate question... it still comes down to "extract archive, follow instructions", whether those instructions are compile source code or run a binary installer.

Comment: Is there some reason you are installing from source code ? See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware

Comment: @bodhi.zazen The OP is *not* installing from source code--[the .txz archives provided for Ubuntu by the Cinelerra project contain prebuilt binaries](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605045/how-to-install-filename-txz-files/605049#605049). See [the download page](http://cinelerra.org/2015/index.php/2014-11-19-00-57-12/cinelerra) for details.

Comment: Is there some reason the OP is running a binary outside of the repositories ?

Answer (score 4):

`.txz` is short for `.tar.xz`, just as `.tgz` is short for `.tar.gz`. You can unpack it like a `.tar.xz` archive:

Run `tar xf *archive*.txz`, since `tar` will automatically figure out how an archive is compressed and decompress accordingly.

Assuming you downloaded [this file](http://cinelerra.org/2015/downloads/cinelerra-4.6.mod-ubuntu-14.04.1-x86_64.txz) (or [that one](http://cinelerra.org/2015/downloads/cinelerra-4.6.mod-ubuntu-14.04.1-x86_64-static.txz)), linked to [from here](http://cinelerra.org/2015/index.php/2014-11-19-00-57-12/cinelerra) and listed under "Ubuntu 14," there are a few points to keep in mind:

1. Most archives for software kindly keep everything in a top-level folder, but this one doesn't! Therefore, I suggest creating a `cinelerra` folder, putting the archive in the folder (or downloading it to there in the first place, if you haven't already), and unpacking it there:

   ```
   mkdir cinelerra
   cd cinelerra
   wget http://cinelerra.org/2015/downloads/cinelerra-4.6.mod-ubuntu-14.04.1-x86_64.txz
   tar xf cinelerra-4.6.mod-ubuntu-14.04.1-x86_64.txz
   ```
2. Generic instructions for installing software from compressed tar archives are often instructions for installing *from source*, as source code is commonly packaged this way. However, Cinelerra is distributed for Ubuntu as a precompiled binary in a compressed tar archive. Thus, as the `README` file says:

   ```
   Run `./cinelerra` from this directory.  That's it.
   ```

Comment: Sorry, linux noob. How do I run cinelerra from the terminal?

Comment: @KevinBrown From the directory in which you unpacked Cinelerra (if you've left that directory, just `cd` back to it), type `./cinelerra` and press enter.

Comment: @EliahKagen I get "Segmentation fault" when I do that.

Comment: @KevinBrown That's a program crash, unfortunately. (If you made a launcher for it to double-click on to run it--this is in regard to [your other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605045/how-to-install-filename-txz-files/605047?noredirect=1#comment845599_605047), then the same problem would occur, so the segfault should probably be troubleshooted first.) It works fine for me--and presumably for some other folks--so we need to figure out what's specific to your situation. Which `.txz` file did you use? And what is shown when you run the command `lsb_release -r; uname -m`?

Answer (score 2):

A `.tgz` or a `.tar.xz` file is not an installer, but a compressed `tar` archive. You need to decompress and to extract the archive to access the files inside it:

1. Open a `Terminal` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Create a new folder to hold the extracted files, for example to create a folder in your `Home` named `extracted_files` run the following command: `mkdir ~/extracted_files`
3. Decompress and extract the archive by running the following command: `tar xf <.tgz_.tar.xz_file_path> -C ~/extracted_files`, where `<.tgz_.tar.xz_file_path>` is the path of the `.tgz` or `.tar.xz` file

Comment: I'm getting errors when I try to do this. Something about an "Unexpected EOF file in archive".

Comment: @KevinBrown From [your other comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605045/how-to-install-filename-txz-files/605049?noredirect=1#comment845584_605049) I'm guessing you were able to unpack the archive using [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/605049/22949), but that's strange because the way given here by kos is just as good and should succeed in all the same circumstances. Unless... is it possible that you had an incomplete or corrupted download of Cinelerra when you followed the advice here, then obtained a good copy by redownloading it using the `wget` command in my answer?

Comment: @EliahKagan I'm guessing that was it. Anyway, now the "Cinelerra" exacutable software start thing doesn't do anything when I click on it

Comment: @KevinBrown I think you might have have a corrupted archive. Try this, run `md5sum <.tgz_.tar.xz_file_path>` and search Google for the output hash, see if you can find any result. If you do, most likely the problem is elsewhere, otherwise most likely your archive is corrupted

Comment: @KevinBrown Meaning that you can find your archive name quoted in some Google search result of course, just to make sure that other people who md5 hashed that file had the same md5 sum result